# Times a particle detector gets stuck in an hour

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

A particle detector has a flaw that makes it get stuck for 10 seconds each time it detects a particle. When it is not stuck assume 100% efficiency (it detects every particle).

Given that particles that pass through the detector follow a Poisson distribution that in 100 seconds got 38.4 particles on average, determine how many times the detector will get stuck in an hour.

---

It is easy to see that on average we expect

$$ 38.4 particles / 100 seconds = 0.384 particles / second$$

Also it is easy to know that with a number of particles very big, the detector will get stuck 3600 seconds / 10 seconds/times = 360 times.

I can predict how many particles will pass through in a given hour, we just multiply the rate by 3600 seconds in an hour but how to account for the percentage of times in which a particle comes when the detector is already stuck so it cannot be stuck a second time?

The amount of times it gets stuck surely must be less than the number of particles going through but how much quantitatively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By [linearity of expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Linearity), the expected number of times the detector gets stuck is the expected number of particles that arrive times the probability that the detector isn't stuck at any given time.

When a particle arrives, the detector gets stuck for $10$ seconds, and then on average it remains [unstuck](https://www.economist.com/democracy-in-america/2007/04/12/billy-pilgrim-has-come-unstuck-in-time) for $0.384^{-1}\mathrm s$. Thus the proportion of time it isn't stuck is

$$
\frac{0.384^{-1}}{10 + 0.384^{-1}}=\frac1{3.84+1}=\frac1{4.84}\;,
$$

and the expected number of times it gets stuck in an hour is

$$
3600\cdot0.384\cdot\frac1{4.84}\approx286\;.
$$

Comment: Shouldn't the fraction be (1/0.384)/(10)? Average time it remains unstuck over time it remains stuck

Comment: @user3105485: No, average time it remains unstuck over total time of one cycle of getting stuck and unstuck -- that's the fraction of time it's unstuck.